# Can i link an NSMutableString to an UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have one NSMutableString and one UITextField. I want my NSMutableString automactic update it's value (set NSMutableString = UITextField.text) when UITextField.text change. Can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass `UITextField` and add that `NSMutableString` as a property. You would override `UITextField`'s `setText:` method, call `[super setText:aString];` and then set that `NSMutableString` property.

If the `NSMutableString` is in another class, you could still do something similar. Instead of setting the value of `NSMutableString` in `setText:`, you would specify a delegate for the class and call the delegate with the updated string value.

Hope this helps!